# How do I stop the annoying "The debugger does not support Hot Fix action" Debugger Console popup?

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, hotfix

Every time I make certain changes while debugging, Netbeans opens the Debugger Console. It's very annoying an counter productive.

[image: Annoying error message!]

How do stop it from opening the console?

Answer (score 1):

You need to uncheck "Open Debugger Console for debugging session".

[image]

Be mindful that when you start a debugging session you will have to manually open the debugger console.